# How to replace the text is on the SharePoint 2010 page using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace the text "**TermsConditions**" with **"Something**" from the below html snippet, would like to use the query to do so but could not achieve it..Any help?

```
    <tr> 
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Terms and Conditions</nobr>
</h3></td>

    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <!-- FieldName="Terms and Conditions"
         FieldInternalName="Terms_x0020_and_x0020_Conditions"
         FieldType="SPFieldBoolean"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
    <input id="ctl00_m_g_ff9223fc_853f_4ee5_bba2_0bd483f90d9e_ctl00_ctl05_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_BooleanField" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_ff9223fc_853f_4ee5_bba2_0bd483f90d9e$ctl00$ctl05$ctl08$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" checked="checked" /><br />
</span>
        TermsConditions

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is this coming from, a form? I am not sure why you are wanting to use jQuery for this rather than, oh editing the name or description of the field or editing the form in SPD. Can you elaborate?

Comment: SPD might not be an option (based on goverance) and he has to result to a CEWP change.

Comment: It is coming the List Form (description of the site column) and do not want to edit the form itself instead of that would like to use any kind of script to do it...

Comment: Why don't you want to just change the field description in List Settings?

Comment: I need to display a hyper link instead of the normal text description..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may help:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/